# how to create Entitlement.plist file in xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone

i am downloading a latest version on xcode 4.2. and its include ios 5.1.
i want to create Entitlement.plist file in my project. So how we create it.
please give me proper steps to create Entitlement.plist file in xcode 4.2.
thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Select the target of your project and scroll down. You'll see the option to add a custom entitlement.

Answer (score 0):

Select the target in your project and scroll down. You'll see the option to add a custom entitlement.[image]

Comment: but it is not sufficient. their are only 2 step to create Entitlement.plist? please give me full steps to create Entitlemt.plist file. thanks...

Comment: are you not be able to create Entitlement.plist by following above steps?

Comment: but above steps are enough to create Entitlement.plist. have you marked the button Enable Entitlements in the first image?

Comment: yes sir.. i had marked it.. and go to that entitlement file and right click on their and select the given option..

Comment: When you check "Entitlements" a new entitlement file is automatically created and added to the project using the default of the project name. then it's sufficient.

Comment: ok its fine. when i click the entitlement file then exact which row select to right click? and have some pass name on that row..?